# I want to use crypto-js module in truffle / app.js

Tags: truffle, nodejs

I want to use npm module "crypto-js" in app.js of truffle_project.
But I can't use it.

[image: Directory structure]

`app.js`:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
// ...
```

I build app, then I open build/index.html by browser, I get the error on Javascript console of google chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'crypto-js'
```

I changed to:

```
var CryptoJS = require("./node_modules/crypto-js");
```

or:

```
var CryptoJS = require("../../node_modules/crypto-js");
```

but I get the same error. I tried absolute path and relative path, I get the error.

How do I do to use `crypto-js` module in `app.js`?

P.S.
install command:

```
# pwd 
~/truffle_project
# npm install crypto-js
```

and the directory structure is default of truffle.

Comment: Have you installed this module using `npm install`?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Yes. I did `npm install crypto-js` .

Comment: Please edit the question and show your install command and logs, otherwise `var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");` works

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I edited.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by myself.

This problem is not truffle side.
I solve to use "crypto-js" of client(bower), and
index.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

done.